# Populating ViewBased table from data in 6 different NSMutable arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays, macos, osx-yosemite

I have 6 different `NSMutable arrays [(Arr(A); Arr(B); etc.]` each of which represents data for one cell of a row in the table.  The array is essentially the key representation.  They are built in a prior classes, passed to the current class and have exactly the same number of string objects (63) in each.  The table is essential a data representation of

Questions:

1. Must I build a `NSDictionary` with '*keys*' and '*objects*'.  How do I build `thatDictionary`.  I have tried various methods stepping through a count loop with no success. I can to find a method for inserting objects for specific keys.
2. Can I load the table directly from the various arrays **without** a `ViewController`.  I have the table and id's laid out but I have not been able to add a `ViewController` to this class - I only have 'Files Owner'.  If this is easiest how can I do that.
3. If needed, how do I take elements of the 6 arrays in order as a comma delimited string in another array that becomes the input to a row of of the table and therefore parsed into the table.

No code to offer because all my attempts w/code have been unsuccessful.

NEED SOME SPECIFIC DIRECTION HERE.

.h

```
     //  ReportsOutput.h
        //  Stamp Collection
        //  Created by Terry Lengel on 4/20/15.
        //  Copyright (c) 2015 Terry Lengel. All rights reserved.

        #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
        #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        #import "ReportsClass.h"

        @interface ReportsOutput : NSWindowController <NSMenuDelegate,NSTableViewDataSource,NSTableViewDelegate,NSApplicationDelegate>{


        // variable and outlet for the table

            IBOutlet NSTableView *rptTable;

        }

        // data element sources

        @property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *tblYrScott;
        @property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *tblYrExt;
        @property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *tblYrYear;
        @property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *tblYrType;
        @property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *tblYrPrice;
        @property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *tblYrDescription;

        // the Display data source array for the table

        @property(strong) NSMutableArray *rptData;

        #pragma mark - Method Declarations

        -(BOOL)conditionData;

        -(NSDictionary *)makeDictionaryRecord:(NSString*)scott withInfo:(NSString*)ext withInfo:(NSString*)year withInfo:(NSString*)type withInfo:(NSString*)price withInfo:(NSString*)Description;

        @end

    .m

        //  ReportsOutput.m
        //  Stamp Collection
        //  Created by Terry Lengel on 4/20/15.
        //  Copyright (c) 2015 Terry Lengel. All rights reserved.

        #import "ReportsOutput.h"
        #import "ReportsClass.h"

        @interface ReportsOutput ()

        @end

        @implementation ReportsOutput

        @synthesize tblYrScott;
        @synthesize tblYrExt;
        @synthesize tblYrType;
        @synthesize tblYrPrice;
        @synthesize tblYrYear;
        @synthesize tblYrDescription;

        @synthesize rptData;

        -(id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window{
            self = [super initWithWindow:window];
            if (self){
                // initialize code here
            }
            return self;

        }


        -(void)windowDidLoad {
            [super windowDidLoad];

            // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
        }

        -(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification{

            //Insert code here to initialize your application
        }

        //  Terminate the app by using the RED button:

        -(BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:
        (NSApplication *)sender{

            return YES;

        }

        -(void)awakeFromNib{

            if (self.conditionData == YES){

                [rptTable reloadData];
            }

        }

        -(BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender{
            return YES;
        }

        -(void)performClose:(id)sender{
            [self close];
        }

        #pragma mark - Table View Data Source

        -(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView{

            return rptData.count;

        }

        -(NSView *) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{

            NSTableCellView *scott = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"Scott" owner:self];

            scott.textField.stringValue = [self.rptData objectAtIndex:row];

            return scott;


        }

        // request for sorting

        -(void) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView sortDescriptorsDidChange:(NSArray *)oldDescriptors{

            // table view received sort request
            //sort the data, then reload the tableView data:

            [rptData sortUsingDescriptors:[rptTable sortDescriptors]];

            [rptTable reloadData];

        }

        -(BOOL)conditionData{

            BOOL conditionData = NO;

            NSString *rPrice;
            NSString *rExt;
            NSString *rYear;
            NSString *rType;
            NSString *rDescription;


            for (int b=0; b<[tblYrScott count]; ++b){

                //condition source data to remove any null appearences

                rExt = [tblYrExt objectAtIndex:b];
                if (rExt == (id)[NSNull null] || rExt.length == 0 ){
                    rExt = @"None";
                }else if ([rExt isEqualToString:@" "]){
                    rExt = @"None";
                }else
                    rExt = [tblYrExt objectAtIndex:b];

                rYear = [tblYrYear objectAtIndex:b];
                if (rYear == (id)[NSNull null] || rYear.length == 0 ){
                    rYear = @" ";
                }else
                    rYear = [tblYrYear objectAtIndex:b];

                rType = [tblYrType objectAtIndex:b];
                if (rType == (id)[NSNull null] || rType.length == 0 ){
                    rType = @" ";
                }else
                    rType = [tblYrType objectAtIndex:b];

                rPrice = [tblYrPrice objectAtIndex:b];
                if (rPrice == (id)[NSNull null] || rPrice.length == 0 ){
                    rPrice = @"n/r";
                }else
                    rPrice = [tblYrPrice objectAtIndex:b];

                rDescription = [tblYrDescription objectAtIndex:b];
                if (rDescription == (id)[NSNull null] || rDescription.length == 0 ){
                    rDescription = @" ";
                }else
                    rDescription = [tblYrDescription objectAtIndex:b];

                NSDictionary *rptData = @{@"Scott":[tblYrScott objectAtIndex:b],@"Ext":rExt,@"Year":rYear,@"Type":rType,@"Price":rPrice,@"Description":rDescription};

            }

            //[rptTable reloadData];

            return conditionData = YES;
        }


        -(NSDictionary*) makeDictionaryRecord:(NSString *)scott withInfo: (NSString *)ext withInfo: (NSString *)year withInfo: (NSString *)type withInfo: (NSString *)price withInfo: (NSString *)description{

            NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:scott,@"Scott",ext,@"Ext",year,@"Year",type,@"Type",price,@"Price",description,@"Description", nil];

           return dict;

        }

        @end

Data Sample:

2015-04-25 12:20:49.251 StampsProjectDev[2981:591183]  rptData = {
    Description = "Lunar New Year - Horse";
    Ext = None;
    Price = "n/r";
    Scott = 4846;
    Type = C;
    Year = 2014;
}
2015-04-25 12:20:49.252 StampsProjectDev[2981:591183]  rptData = {
    Description = "Jimi Hendrix";
    Ext = None;
    Price = "n/r";
    Scott = 4880;
    Type = C;
    Year = 2014;
}
2015-04-25 12:20:49.252 StampsProjectDev[2981:591183]  rptData = {
    Description = "Charlton Heston";
    Ext = None;
    Price = "n/r";
    Scott = 4892;
    Type = C;
    Year = 2014;
}
2015-04-25 12:20:49.252 StampsProjectDev[2981:591183]  rptData = {
    Description = "Janice Joplin";
    Ext = None;
    Price = "n/r";
    Scott = 4916;
    Type = C;
    Year = 2014;
}
2015-04-25 12:20:49.252 StampsProjectDev[2981:591183]  rptData = {
    Description = "Ralph Ellison";
    Ext = None;
    Price = "n/r";
    Scott = 4866;
    Type = C;
    Year = 2014;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can share what the data for one cell would look like?

Comment: Parallel arrays are often difficult to work with.  How about creating a custom class that contains properties for all the cells in a single row?  Then your "prior classes" would create one array where each element was an instance of the custom class.  When you want to populate the table, get one object from the array that matches the row number and ask it for the cell data.

Comment: When you say 'data for one cell', do you mean a column or a single cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Must I build a NSDictionary with 'keys' and 'objects'. How do I build thatDictionary. I have tried various methods stepping through a count loop with no success. I can to find a method for inserting objects for specific keys.

Not required, but advisable.

```
// assume six arrays are array0, array1, ...
// assume array0.count == array1.count == etc
for (int i=0; i<array0.count; ++i) {
    NSDictionary *di = @{ @"ar0":array0[i], @"ar1":array1[i],... };
}
```

But a better idea is an NSObject subclass that you create that is meaningful to your users and has properties from corresponding elements from the arrays  (call it `MeaningfulObject`)....

```
// in your datasource's interface definition
@property(strong) NSMutableArray *myArrayOfMeaningfulObjects;

self.myArrayOfMeaningfulObjects = [@[] mutableCopy];
// assume array0.count == array1.count == etc
for (int i=0; i<array0.count; ++i) {
    MeaningfulObject *mi = [MeaningfulObject meaningfulObjectWithAttribute0:array0[i] attribute1:array1[i]... ];
    [self.myArrayOfMeaningfulObjects addObject:mi];
}
```

> Can I load the table directly from the various arrays without a ViewController. I have the table and id's laid out but I have not been able to add a ViewController to this class - I only have 'Files Owner'. If this is easiest how can I do that.

The table loads itself.  Your job is to provide it with a *datasource*, which is an array of objects representing rows.  Most people opt to make the view controller who's view contains the table act as the datasource, but the table's datasource can be any object.  The two required parts of the `NSTableViewDatasource` protocol are (1) `numberOfRowsInTableView:` like this:

```
return self.myArrayOfMeaningfulObjects.count;
```

And (2) `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` like this:

```
MeaningfulObject *mrow = self.myArrayOfMeaningfulObjects[indexPath.row];
// configure a tableview cell using mrow's attributes
cell.textLabel.text = mrow.attribute0;
```

> If needed, how do I take elements of the 6 arrays in order as a comma delimited string in another array that becomes the input to a row of of the table and therefore parsed into the table.

Don't understand this one, but hopefully a good answer is implicit in the foregoing

**EDIT**, Upon review of the code, it seems to me that you've nearly got it.  The code has declared an array that will be the basis of the datasource, like this:

```
@property(strong) NSMutableArray *rptData;
```

Good, but a consequential mistake is made here:

```
NSDictionary *rptData = @{@"Scott":[tblYrScott objectAtIndex:b],@"Ext":rExt,@"Year":rYear,@"Type":rType,@"Price":rPrice,@"Description":rDescription};
```

That's a dictionary which looks as if it represents a single row in the table, named confusingly like the NSArray property.  It looks as if the dictionary is built then abandoned on the iteration of the loop, overwritten by the object for the next row.  To make this work, the objects representing the rows must be added to the datasource, like this:

```
// renamed rptData dictionary to rowDictionary
NSDictionary *rowDictionary = @{@"Scott":[tblYrScott objectAtIndex:b],@"Ext":rExt,@"Year":rYear,@"Type":rType,@"Price":rPrice,@"Description":rDescription};
[self.rptData addObject:rowDictionary];
```

Comment: The question is tagged `OS X`, so shouldn't that be `NSTableViewDataSource`?

Comment: Not to be picky, but `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `numberOfRowsInSection:` aren't in that protocol.

Comment: The first part of the answer helped me create the NSDictionary, however I still do not get the data listed.  I can do a NSLog to show that data, so i know it is there. But I appear to have a problem associating the data array created with the table.. Is there a routine I am missing to associate the two.

Comment: The key to it are those datasource methods.  Check out this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html

Comment: Read Doc, implemented code for both protocols but no data displayed.  Have tried both View and Cell attributes with data conditioned to remove any null statements.  ID's set.  Any way you could review my .h and .m files with short list of data? I am puzzled.

Comment: sure.  please edit the code into your question, trying to put the least amount of code possible that demonstrates the problem.  (in fact, i'd advise a brand new mini-project called, say, "FricknTableView" that starts with an array with dictionaries (or I hope custom objects) and just tries to get that right.

Comment: code provided from class.  Is there any way I can send.xib file?  I was not sure about making sample as suggested since this class actually acquires data from arrays built in another class.

Comment: @TLL - please see edit.  We can probably get along without the xib.  Just please make sure that the table outlet, and delegate/datasource refs are setup either in the xib or code.

Comment: Made change - 'rptData' Log output is null.  Is table View or Cell Based?

Comment: got rptData output but no cells with reload

Comment: Made some adjustments in awakeFromNib procedure and table now fills.  Your help with Dictionary and Data file was invaluable.  Thank you.